# How do I get the total number of students who are only active

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables that store data for students - the **students** table and **student_session** table

**students table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `admission_no` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `roll_no` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admission_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rte` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobileno` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'yes',
  `disable_at` date NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**student_session table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student_session` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `session_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `route_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hostel_room_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vehroute_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transport_fees` float(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `fees_discount` float(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `is_active` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'no',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now, I've been able to get the total number of students in a class using this query

```
 public function Gettotalstudents($session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
    {
        $this->db->select('student_id');
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
        $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
        return $this->db->count_all_results('student_session');
    }
```

However, there are some students who have been disabled for non-payment of school fees or those that have left the school permanently.
The problem is since these students were only disabled and not deleted, the query still counts them to the active students.

Now, I want to exclude the disabled students from being counted.

**Note** - in the students table structure, the ***'is_active'*** row stores data for if a student is active or disabled. 'yes' means a student is active, 'no' means a student has been disabled.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or a little more succinctly, you can just use the mysql `COUNT()` function with `AS`:

```
public function Gettotalstudents($session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
    {
        $this->db->select('COUNT(ss.student_id) as total');
        $this->db->from('student_session ss');
        $this->db->join('students st', 'st.id = ss.student_id');
        $this->db->where(array('st.is_active'=> 'yes','ss.session_id' => $session_id, 'ss.section_id' => $section_id, 'ss.class_id' => $class_id));
        return $this->db->get()->row()->total;
    }
```

Comment: students are being counted from student_session but students are being disabled from the students table. How do you join the two tables and get the is_active record?

Comment: I updated my response. This should work, though i can't test it here.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the **is_active** field to boolean.
Join the student table with **student_session.student_id = students.student_id**, and  filter by the **is_active** field in student_session

> Try this for active students in table students

```
public function Gettotalstudents($session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
{
    $this->db->select('student_session.student_id');
    $this->db->from("student_session,students"); //session table and student table
    $this->db->where('student_session.student_id', 'student_id.student_id'); //join tables
    $this->db->where('student_session.session_id', $session_id);
    $this->db->where('student_session.section_id', $section_id);
    $this->db->where('student_session.class_id', $class_id);
    $this->db->where('student_id.is_active', 'yes'); //only active
    return $this->db->count_all_results(); // count active
}
```

> Try this for active students in table student_session

```
 public function Gettotalstudents($session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
{
    $this->db->select('student_id');
    $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
    $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
    $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
    $this->db->where('is_active', 'yes');
    return $this->db->count_all_results('student_session');
}
```

Comment: students are being counted from student_session but students are being disabled from the students table. How do you join the two tables and get the is_active record?

Comment: student_session should be active users in session, and studets should be if the account is activated or disabled, what do you want to know? Active accounts or Active users in session? @Mary4bills

Comment: okay! I want the Active accounts in students table

Comment: make a query to students table, why you use session_students table if you want active  accounts in student table? @Mary4bills

Comment: I get this error Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on bool